# Обновить UITableView из другого ViewController'а

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Уважаемые гуру, подскажите как обновить таблицу после изменения массива данных из другого контроллера.

//STNViewController.h

```
@interface STNViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *mytableView;
- (void)reloadData;
@end
```

// STNProfileViewController.m

```
- (void)reloadData{
[[self mytableView] reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[STNSingleton singleton].profilesNames count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString* const cellAdd = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellAdd];
cell.textLabel.text = [[STNSingleton singleton].profilesNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

//Класс, где обновляются данные STNProfileViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
STNProfile *profile = [[STNProfile alloc]init];
[profile setProfileWithExercises:[exersisesField.text intValue] andName:[profileName text]];

[[[STNSingleton singleton] profilesNames] addObject: profile.nameP]; //данные обновились.

UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [self storyboard];
STNViewController *stnvc = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"STNViewController"];
[stnvc reloadData]; //метод вызывается, но таблица не перезагружается...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, Вам даже не нужен синглетон (как я понял с массивом).
Во втором контроллере, где создаются данные, создайте массив, и в него запихивайте данные (объекты).

В .h-файле этого контроллера пишите примерно такое (код взял из своего проекта, имя поменяете):

```
@protocol RegistrationAndEditDelegate

- (void)updateUserData: (NSArray *)arrayChangedParams;

@end

@interface RegistrationAndEditViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<RegistrationAndEditDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

В методе, где заполнили массив данными (- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender), пишите:

```
[self.delegate updateUserData:params];
```

где "парамс" - массив с данными.

Теперь в контроллере с таблицей подключаете предыдущий контроллер и подписываетесь на делегат (в точности как с табличными делегатами датасоурсом и дататэйблом), и в любом методе, с которого вызываете контроллер с массивом (в моем случае):

```
- (void)editPersonalData {

    RegistrationAndEditViewController *editView = [[RegistrationAndEditViewController alloc] init];
    editView.delegate = self;
    }
```

И в этом же контроллере реализуете метод протокола, в который Вам придет массив с данными. И уже в табличном контроллере создайте пустой массив и дополняйте его новыми данными, а также после этого делаем релоаддата.

Для более большой ясности рекомендую почитать делегирование. Сам недавно понял, как оно работает. В принципе ничего сложного нет. Удачи.

P.S. В контроллере с таблицей, например, метод, принимающий данные массива, т.е. реализуем метод делегата:

```
- (void)updateUserData:(NSArray *)arrayChangedParams {

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

        UILabel *changedLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:i + 50];
        NSString *attributedData = arrayChangedParams[i - 1];
        NSString *titlesData = NSLocalizedString(_labelTitles[i], nil);
        NSString *fullUserData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", titlesData, arrayChangedParams[i - 1]];
        NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullUserData];

        [text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange([titlesData length], [attributedData length])];

        [changedLabel setAttributedText:text];
    }

}
```

Comment: Ок, дома попробую.

Т.е. при вызове метода 
- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender

на строке 
[self.delegate updateUserData:mySomeArray];

вызовется метод
- (void)updateUserData:(NSArray *)arrayChangedParams

так?

Блин, я походу вообще дерево, перечитал кучу толкований делегатов и все равно пока не совсем понятно. Киньте, пожалуйста, линк на литературу, которую вы читали и все поняли)

Comment: типа того. и в нем обработаете переданный массив объектов, после чего сможете сделать релоад таблицы.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо! Только до сих пор не понял, почему подход, который был без делегата, не работает. Ведь он вызывал метод, но таблица не обновляла данные.