# Как запомнить класс viewControle, переходя на другой контроллер?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией. Переходя от одного класса viewcontroler к другому, первый уходит из памяти, и при возврате обратно к нему он создается заново.

Как можно сохранить его, чтоб при возврате он продолжал работать с того места, когда перешли к другому контроллеру?

Конечно, можно сделать все переменные глобальными, но это не выход. В MAC OS не вызвало такой проблемы, а вот на iOS возникла.

Comment: Если работаете с NavigationViewController, то такой проблемы быть не должно

Comment: Как у вас переход происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Была похожая проблема... при возврате на главную форму из модального окна создается экземпляр главного окна заново) проблема действительно происходит если не использовать навигейшнКонтроллер... 
Нужно закрывать модальное окно так(swift):*

```
@IBAction func backToMain(sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Используйте делегат (протокол). При возврате (при использовании протокола) вызовется метод (опять же, прописанный в протоколе и реализованный в первом вьюконтроллере), в котором можно обновить данные/контролы на первом вьюконтроллере.

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/379541/objective-c-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-uitableview-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-viewcontroller-%D0%B0)